# Jenkins job is getting stuck at authentication realm

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins job is getting stuck at below location after authentication realm:

```
D:\jenkins-docker\workspace\JenkinsPipeline>svn copy -r HEAD http://xyz/svn/branches/B123 http://xyz/svn/tags/G_UI -m "Tagging at Revision" 
Authentication realm: <http://xyz:80> wandisco
*loader icon*
```

I am running the job using jenkinsfiles.

Tried steps:
Deleted subversion/auth folder and manually checkout.

PS. This job is running previously and now all job having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `svn` in scripts / in unattended mode, you should specify [`--non-interactive`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive) option. In this particular case you may also need to specify the `--username` and `--password` options.

Comment: --non-interactive resulted in: svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
--username <user> --password <password> resolved the issue.

I wonder though how to have it extract these parameters on it's own (Linux)

Comment: @Wakaka add `--username` and `--password` to your command (and specify correct username and password as values of these options).